# Android WebView underscore key of keyboard underlines words instead of working normally

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a standard WebView Android application written in Kotlin. When I fill a textarea or any other kind of input in my WebView app I expect underscores to be a normal character just_like_this.

Instead it behaves like this: _ underlines characters. _ can even put indefinitely above each other. Picture:

[image: underscore]

I don't know why it behaves this way and it's not expected. I did not find anything about this on the Internet.

Comment: Did you try on other phones? Other locales even, maybe it's a localization thing?

Comment: @Nicolas I tried on my emulator as well as on my phone, with different Android versions as well. Yes, I thought about localization as well. I'm using a German keyboard. But I've never seen anything like it before.

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the page you're using, something in javascript? A textfield attribute perhaps?